# Variables in .env is empty when deploy to production using ZEIT Now

Tags: production-environment, vercel

I have built a project from scratch using React and deploy it to ZEIT. In development mode, all variables in .env file are loaded(using dotenv-webpack) and everything works perfect. 
By default, ZEIT Now will ignore .env in production so I put all my .env variables to now.json like this

```
{ "version": 2, "alias": "goccuathi", "regions": [ "sin1" ], "build": { "env": { "OWNER_EMAIL": "@gct_owner-email", "TINYMCE_KEY": "@gct_tinymce-key", "GA_ID": "@gct_ga-key" } }, "env": { "OWNER_EMAIL": "@gct_owner-email", "TINYMCE_KEY": "@gct_tinymce-key", "GA_ID": "@gct_ga-key" } }
```

And here is logs:

```
{"id":"dpl_2wDwTfqRGa46WYsCeSh31zmsHnke","lambdas":[{"id":"bld_pw942tu0q","createdAt":1585988984285,"entrypoint":"package.json","readyState":"INITIALIZING","readyStateAt":1585988984285,"output":[]}],"public":false,"readyState":"QUEUED","regions":["sin1"],"url":"goccuathi-9mtrc5d9i.now.sh","version":2,"build":{"env":["OWNER_EMAIL","TINYMCE_KEY","GA_ID"]},"builds":[{"src":"package.json","use":"@now/static-build","config":{"zeroConfig":true}}],"createdAt":1585988983745,"createdIn":"sfo1","env":[],"meta":{},"name":"goccuathi","ownerId":"cYIfFUzo4cG4SkSwFNEEOLE5","plan":"hobby","routes":[],"target":"production","functions":null,"projectId":"QmcrHSmFE6x35GgZuxnkkQfJdjW3K5RjKG1yNL4EBrxgjm","type":"LAMBDAS","team":null,"creator":{"uid":"cYIfFUzo4cG4SkSwFNEEOLE5","username":"anhthi-ieig"},"bootedAt":1585988983745,"buildingAt":1585988983745,"status":"QUEUED","alias":["goccuathi.now.sh","goccuathi.anhthi-ieig.now.sh"],"aliasAssigned":false}
```

My .env variables in production are empty.
What am I doing wrong?